# xamarin forms - when running the application its open the ios phone emulator and stacks there with a black screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am a new to xamarin and I am trying to develop my first 'Hello World!' 
 mobile application using cross platform App(Xamarin.Forms).

I am using visual studio 2017 community edition and when I am trying to run the application for ios, then after 1-2 minutes it opens the emulator with a black screen and stucks there.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are your computer running on? You can't run iOS apps on Windows unless you have connected an iOS machine to Visual Studio as well.

If you are using a Mac for development, what solutions have you tried so far to get the emulator running?

Comment: My computer is running Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (4.00 GB RAM) and I have connected it with Mac macOS High Siera to make the debucking

Comment: Alright then you are all good there. Have you tried starting the emulator before running the app? If it wont start at all, try lowering the settings for the emulator, like lowering the resolution for example.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue. I've been able to resolve it by restarting the mac, restarting visual studio, stopping the app and trying to redeploy. Usually one of these things works. I find the first time staring the app in an emulator tends to take a lot longer since the emulator has to spin up, so redeploying the app a second time makes it work.